# Create cloud admin user

Tags: javascript, cloud, admin, appcelerator

I would like to create admin users, I've tried the following unsuccessfully. Any clue?

Thanks in advance

```
require("ti.cloud").Users.create({
    email:$.email.value,
    first_name: $.firstname.value,
    last_name: $.lastname.value,
    password: $.password1.value,
    password_confirmation: $.password1.value,
    admin:true,
}, function (e) {
    Ti.API.info(e);
    if (e.success) {
        //User created not admin...
    } else {
        Ti.API.info('Error:\n' +((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: No error, the created user seems to be a regular user. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?